# arima(p,order=c(2,1,2)) and arima(diff(p),order=c(2,0,2) give different coefficients

Tags: r, arima

Here's the data `p[,6]` and the coefficients.

```
    1132.99 1136.52 1137.14 1141.69 1144.98 1146.98 1136.22 1145.68 1148.46 1136.03
     1150.23 1138.04 1116.48 1091.76 1096.78 1092.17 1097.50 1084.53 1073.87 1089.19

    arima(p[,6],order = c(2,1,2))

Call:
arima(x = p[, 6], order = c(2, 1, 2))

Coefficients:
         ar1      ar2     ma1     ma2
      -1.235  -0.7514  1.4880  0.9999
s.e.   0.389   0.3134  0.3636  0.1821

sigma^2 estimated as 107.5:  log likelihood = -72.3,  aic = 154.61

    arima(diff(p[,6]),order = c(2,0,2))

Call:
arima(x = diff(p[, 6]), order = c(2, 0, 2))

Coefficients:
         ar1      ar2      ma1     ma2  intercept
      1.0886  -0.9142  -1.2194  0.9998    -2.2153
s.e.  0.7533   0.3343   0.9239  0.3359     2.2698

sigma^2 estimated as 110.2:  log likelihood = -72.31,  aic = 156.61
```

Why do they give different results?

Comment: Sorry about the format. Even the first coefficient has different signal. -1.235 and 1.0886

Comment: Note that it fits an intercept in the second. Check out the include.mean parameter and associated documentation.